# How can I search for a contact by its phone number?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, search

Is it possible to search for a contact by phone number in Froyo ? How ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTC's Sense UI gives you this functionality out of the box.  In the Phone app if you start typing the phone number, it will filter your contacts that include either that number, or the contact's name via T9 representation.

If you are not running Sense IU, I suggest trying 3rd-party apps that imitate the HTC Dialer functionality.  Try [Dialer One](https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.mek.DialerOne) or [aContacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.mek.aContacts), for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Will 3rd party Contact managers or dialers allow integrate with Facebook & Twitter contacts as the stock contact manager does ?

Comment: They should - they simply read your phone's Contacts database.  So as long as your accounts are all synced up with Google/Facebook/Twitter/etc., the contacts should be visible to 3rd-party apps.

Comment: I tried Dialer One and aContacts and I settled on GO Contacts but they are all fine. Thank you very much @Chahk.

Answer (score 5):

Choose 'Contacts', than 'Keypad' and start entering the phone number.

On my Galaxy S running Froyo 2.2.1 this displays a dropdown box with a number of how many numbers start with the characters entered.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on CM7. Maybe it's a TouchWiz feature?

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Nexus One with Gingerbread either.

Comment: This worked on Droid X with Motoblur after the .234 upgrade, but not on Liberty 2.0.  It is definitely dependent on which ROM or skinned Froyo you are on.

Comment: It does not work for me either. I have G1 with Laszlo ROM which is based on CM6.

Comment: Just to be complete: you have to start entering the first digits of the number. It's now a 'find anywhere'. F.i. my phone numbers start with the Belgian country number 32, so I have to start typing

Comment: Just to be complete here: you have to start typing the number from the front. F.i. my phone numbers start with the Belgian country nr 32, so I have to start typing '32' followed by the actual phone number.

Comment: For me, it's not "Contacts" but the main Phone app (Lineage OS - Android 9). Start typing a number and it shows any matches from your contacts. Leave off the starting zero, or international code (+44 or +33 etc.), and it will find numbers stored either way.